# How nuclear force is scalar in isospin space?

Tags: nuclear-physics, isospin-symmetry

In Introductory Nuclear Physics by Samuel Shaw Ming Wong (Pg. 75), it's given that nuclear force is two body in nature and scalar in isospin space. What is meant by scalar in isospin space?

Comment: ZerotheHero has explained the meaning of isoscalar, but the assertion that nuclear force is purely isoscalar is     incorrect. The attraction between a neutron and a proton is slightly stronger than P-P or N'-N. That is why the deuteron exists but no bound state of two neutrons has been found.

Comment: @LewisMiller This is not quite right. Even if the interaction is iso-scalar, it can be different in the $I_{tot}=0$ (deuteron) and $I_{tot}=1$ (nn,pp) channel. This is the (main) reason why the deuteron is bound and nn is not. Isospin breaking is responsible for the small difference between nn and pp.

Comment: @Thomas You are correct

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the nucleon-nucleon force has many descriptions that are phenomenological, or effective field theories, that are not fundamental QCD results, so it's very difficult to make absolute statements about the interaction.

An example of an iso-scalar piece of it the one-pion exchange potential:

$ V \propto ({\vec \tau}_1\cdot{\vec \tau}_2) \frac{e^{-\mu r}}{r} \big[ {\vec \sigma}_1\cdot{\vec \sigma}_2 + (1+\frac{3}{\mu r}+\frac{3}{ (\mu r)^2})[ 3(\vec{\sigma}_1\cdot\hat{r})(\vec{\sigma_2}\cdot\hat{r})-({\vec \sigma_1}\cdot{\vec \sigma}_2) ]\big]$.

The 2 terms in the square brackets are spin-scalar and tensor, respectively. Other options are vector ($\vec{\sigma}_1 \pm \vec{\sigma}_2$) and axial-vector ($\vec{\sigma}_1 \times \vec{\sigma}_2$).

The same applies in iso-space, with $\sigma \rightarrow \tau $. This potential is iso-scalar because it depends on the dot product of the nucleon iso-spins.

What that means for the Deuteron is that the isoscalar state:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|np\rangle - |pn\rangle)$

has a very different one-pion-exchange than the iso-vector state:

$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|np\rangle + |pn\rangle)$

even though they both have $I_3=0$.

Answer (score 0):

It means that it is just a number.

A vector is a 2 or 3 dimensional data point. A scalar is a 1 dimensional datapoint. A nuclear force being scalar in isospin space (meaning a fixed or irrelevant spin) just means that if spin is irrelevant the nuclear force can still have value.

The only reason this is significant is because the elecrormagentic and nuclear force are sometimes talked of as equivalent, so this highlights a difference between them. Magnetic fields can be nil and nuclear force can still exist.

Of course it is impossible to understand what exactly the author is getting at without more context.